# plesk atomic updates not up to date, and priorities

Tags: yum

I have atomic Repos setup with priority 1.  My RKHunter has been telling me for the last few days that some of my packages are not up to date:

```
Warning: Application 'httpd', version '2.2.3', is out of date, and possibly a security risk.
Warning: Application 'named', version '9.3.6-P1', is out of date, and possibly a security risk.
Warning: Application 'openssl', version '0.9.8e', is out of date, and possibly a security risk.
Warning: Application 'sshd', version '4.3p2', is out of date, and possibly a security risk.
```

Should I be concerned about this?  Running YUM update tells me the following:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www3.atomicorp.com
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
Excluding Packages from Plesk Server Administrator
Finished
829 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

829 packages seems like a lot to me, and I find it strange that atomic isn't up-to-date on these packages.  Is RKHunter just reporting it wrong?  Do I have something set up wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend you post this on the Atomic forums:

http://www.atomicorp.com/forums

In answer to your question, probably not.  rkhunter is using the literal version number, and many vendors backport fixes to earlier versions of the software - and hence the version number does not change.  The Atomic forums are also maintained by security experts, so its extremely unlikely they would ever miss a security issue.